# Is there any way to Disable span tag in Dynamics Crm 2013

Tags: html, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-crm-2013

Can we Disable Span tag in dynamics crm 2013.is there anyways to disable span tag. i tried the below code

```
function disableSubgrid()
{
debugger;
    var subgrid=document.getElementById("Contacts_span").disabled=true;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what your code does but it has wrong syntax anyway. Should be something like:

```
function disableSubgrid()
{
    var subgrid=document.getElementById("Contacts_span");
    if (subgrid != null){
        subgrid.disabled = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually i'm trying to disabling the subgrid by using span id.but its not disabling the subgrid.could you plz clarify me.how to disable the subgrid.above code is not working

Comment: I just corrected your code to have correct syntax. There are no supported way to disable grid (believe me this is weird and stupid requirement) but you can try to check following thread - [http://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/117/t/126304.aspx](http://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/117/t/126304.aspx)